# Django and javascript - how to use the value of dropdown box to access the static image stored on server using the static tag

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

```
{% load static %}                                                         line 1
<html>                                                                    line 2
<head>                                                                    line 3
<meta charset="UTF-8">                                                    line 4
</head>
<body>
<select id="ddlViewBy">
<option value="Pranamasana.jpg">Pranamasana</option>
</select>
<img id='cat' crossorigin="anonymous" height = "620" width = "620"/>
<button onclick = "myfun()">button</button>
<script>
function myfun() {
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById("cat").src = "{% static 'Pranamasana.jpg' %}";        line 16  
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Even though I have a drop down box I am hard coding the name of the image to be accessed in line 16.
I want to know the way if I can use the string 'struser' so that the image selected by user can be displayed without hard coding.

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

I am using django and this is  a html page in my project

Comment: String coordination works in Javascript. `"{% static " + "'" + user + "'" + " %}"`

Comment: ' document.getElementById("cat").src =   "{% static " + " ' " + user + " ' " + " %}" ' ;' gives me the error **TemplateSyntaxError at /result

Could not parse the remainder: ''" + user + "'" + "' from '" + "'" + user + "'" + "'**

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've answered your question. Let's continue the discussion there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django template executes your code before the javascript does so you can't really use the javascript concatenate string adding. So the best way is to use `{% get_static_prefix %}`

```
var staticUrl = "{% get_static_prefix %}"
var strUsr = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById("cat").src = staticUrl + strUsr
```